# How to make a Windows CLI from a Mac

Tags: c, windows, macos, command-line-interface

Wondering how to make a command-line interface / tool on a Mac that works on Windows. I know you can create an exe from the entire [node.js repo](https://github.com/zeit/pkg), but I'm wondering how to do this at a lower level. Writing some C library and compiling with VisualStudio perhaps. Wondering what a hello world CLI (something that just prints hello world to the terminal) would look like for Windows, when compiling/testing from a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce a Windows executable on a Mac you need a cross-compiler. You can use either Brew or MacPorts to install MinGW (or MinGW-w64 for x86_64 binaries) toolchain.

See ["Install MinGW-w64 using Brew"](https://brewinstall.org/Install-mingw-w64-on-Mac-with-Brew/) or select the required port from [this list](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=mingw).

After installing, you will have the 'i686-w64-mingw32-gcc' binary and installed C run-time library, so that you may compile your 'app.c' file with

```
/path/to/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o app.exe app.c
```

command.

As a starter, I would use a "Hello, World" test like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { return printf("Hello, world!\n"); }
```

If your CLI tool depends on third-party libraries, you would have to compile all libraries using 'i686-w64-mingw32-gcc' compiler (this usually requires some library-specific setup in each case).

To quickly debug some platform-independent things you may either compile the same app for MacOS or run compiled .exe file with Wine emulator.

Comment: what if it's project that need configure and make??

Comment: For configure/make projects you have to specify sysroot, CC and other system variables so that ./configure finds a required mingw environment.